# Why would AVPlayerItem not honor AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed setting?

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am trying to change the audio pitch of an AVPlayerItem depending on the rate I send to an AVPlayer.

To do this, I am initializing an AVPlayerItem with an AVAsset specifying the 'AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed', like such:

```
AVPlayerItem *nPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        [nPlayerItem setAudioTimePitchAlgorithm:AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed];
```

I then attach the playerItem to an AVPlayer, however when I set the rate of the AVPlayer to less than 1 or greater than 1, the pitch does not change. Instead the AVPlayerItem uses the 'AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral' algorithm and does not honor the algorithm I specified. I am targeting 10.9 and building against 10.9. According to the docs, this feature is available as of 10.9.

Comment: Once I initialized my AVPlayerItem, I did examine the item's 'canPlaySlowForward' property and it returned NO which I find odd given that I can set the rate less than 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by 1) adding the playerItem to an AVPlayer 2) setting up Key value observing (KVO) on the player item's status:

```
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {

       if ([object isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerItem class]] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
           AVPlayerItem *nPlayerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
           if([nPlayerItem status] == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay){
               [nPlayerItem setAudioTimePitchAlgorithm:AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed];
           }
       }
 }
```

Only once the playerItem achieved the status 'AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay', could I successfully set the AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed on the playerItems's audioTimePitchAlgorithm.